# C++ How to handle the returned value of lambda expression used in for_each loop?

Tags: c++, foreach, lambda

I'm learning about lambda expressions, and I'd like to know how I can use or get access to the value returned by a lambda expression used in a for_each loop.

For example, suppose I have the following:

```
vector<string> names;
for_each(names.begin(), names.end(),
    [](string aName) -> string {
    string newName = aName + "some text";
    return newName;
});
```

How can I get the `newName` returned by each call to the lambda expression?

Answer (score 8):

Instead of `for_each`, you probably want `transform`.

```
vector<string> names;
vector<string> output(names.size());
transform(names.begin(), names.end(), output.begin(),
    [](string aName) -> string {
    string newName = aName + "some text";
    return newName;
});
```

You can also use the back inserter so that you don't have to pre-allocate the size of the output vector. For efficiency, it is probably also better to pass the string as a const& as well:

```
std::vector<std::string> names;
std::vector<std::string> output;
output.reserve(names.size());
std::transform(names.begin(), names.end(), std::back_inserter(output),
    [](const std::string& aName) -> std::string {
    return aName + "some text";
});
```

If you use `for_each`, you will need to capture the output container by reference:

```
std::vector<std::string> names;
std::vector<std::string> output;
output.reserve(names.size());
std::for_each(names.begin(), names.end(), 
    [&output](const std::string& aName) {
    output.push_back(aName + "some text");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

While `transform`'s an excellent fit, I think it's worth mentioning that you can shoehorn `for_each` into service in a more imperative / less declarative way.  Learning to do so can be less disruptive to your application-level programming "flow" than digging around in `<algorithm>` docs if you're trying to code up solutions to small problems quickly while learning C++.  The data-processing logic is the more important skill.

```
vector<string> names;
vector<string> results;
results.reserve(names.size());
for_each(names.begin(), names.end(),
    [](const string& name) {
        results.push_back(name + "some text");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<pair<int,string>> vecpair;
vecpair.push_back(make_pair(1000,  "abc"));
vecpair.push_back(make_pair(1298,  "def"));


std::for_each(vecpair.begin(), vecpair.end(), 
    [&](pair<int,string>item){ sumStr+= " "+ item.second ; }    );
```

I tried above code with delta expression, seem to do what I want